# Flutter - Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't run my Flutter app and I am getting this error:

```
Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                     │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then │
│ update /Users/blabla/Desktop/projects/blabla/android/build.gradle:           │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'
```

I already updated /android/build.gradle file like this to include newest version:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I also have this in gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.4-all.zip
```

My Flutter version is:

```
Flutter 3.19.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision abb292a07e (4 days ago) • 2024-02-20 14:35:05 -0800
Engine • revision 04817c99c9
Tools • Dart 3.3.0 • DevTools 2.31.1
```

Whatever I try I am getting back to this error, so I am out of ideas and I would appreciate some help.

Adding app/build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "hr.ags.blabla"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "hr.ags.blabla"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}
```

settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
}

include ":app"
```

Comment: Can you include the content of your `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle files`?

Comment: `settings.gradle` agrees with my own. In `build.gradle`, you should delete the `dependencies {}` line at the bottom. Additionally, try replacing the values of `compileSdkVersion` and `ndkVersion` in your android block with     `flutter.compileSdkVersion` and `flutter.ndkVersion`.

Comment: Also, have you already tried deleting the `build` folder and rerunning `flutter run`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two `.../build.gradle` files in the project:

```
`android/build.gradle`
`android/app/build.gradle`
```

Make sure that the `plugins` block (previously `buildscript` block) is in the `android/app/build.gradle`, not `android/build.gradle`.

---

Check out [this article](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply) about migrating the imperative apply block.

the `buildscript` block in `android/app/build.gradle` should be replaced with a `plugins` block at the top of your file, like

```
plugins {
  id 'com.android.application'
  id 'kotlin-android'
  id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}
```

In `android/settings.gradle` (after any definitions):

```
plugins {
  id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
  id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
  id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
}

:app
```

After which your `android/app/build.gradle` might look like:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

android {
    namespace "<SOMETHING>"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
```

And your `android/build.gradle` file might look like

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I updated it but now I am getting error 

com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
   > Cannot invoke method substring() on null object

and I have already set the compileSdkVersion:

android {
    namespace "hr.ags.blabla"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"

Comment: Also I get this error now as well:

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin']
> Failed to apply plugin 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'.
   > Cannot add task 'generateLockfiles' as a task with that name already exists.

Comment: What happens if you change compileSdkVersion `34` to `flutter.compileSdkVersion`?

Comment: same error with 33 and with 34

Comment: For the `generateLockFiles` error, try running `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` then try `flutter run` again. If the error persists, post your current `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` files

Comment: I tried that as well, but no luck. Added content of files you asked.